# How to enable update during running for Ankhsvn

Tags: visual-studio, svn, ankhsvn

My application makes use of many non-compiled resources whether it be JS, CSS or HTML files.

Is it possible to enable the update ability in Ankhsvn for these kinds of assets? It's troublesome sometimes to cancel the current running process to run an update on a CSS file.

I can update from window's explorer while the project is running, then refresh the file from the visual studio. This makes me think that the above has to be possible.

Any ideas?